# Drupal 7: allow only the homepage to anonymous visitors

Tags: drupal-7

I'm building an administration system on drupal 7. I'm not allowing anonymous users to view published content (for obvious reasons), but I'd like to allow them to view just one single page, the homepage, which has a welcome message and the login form. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually build a small module for sites that require custom functionality not provided by modules I use, in this case you could simply build a module with the following in the module file.

```
mymodule_menu(){
  $items['homepage']=array(
    'title' => 'Home'
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_homepage',
    'access callback' => true,
    'type' => MENU CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['homepage/edit']=array(
    'title' => 'Edit Homepage'
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_homepage_edit'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU CALLBACK,
  );
}
function mymodule_homepage(){
  return variable_get('homepage_content',''); 
}
function mymodule_homepage_edit(){
  $form['body']=array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Body',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit
  );
}
function mymodule_homepage_edit_submit($form, $form_state=array()){
  variable_set('homepage_content',$form_state['values']['body']);
}
```

you need a .info file for the module with drupal, no frills, pretty self explanatory if you just open up one from another module to see how they look.

The benefit to handling it this way is the flexibility of adding other custom functionality to this same module down the line.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to make a module, but I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's pretty easy really, just create a folder with the name you would like to give your module... say "MySiteMod", then create a file inside that folder called "MySiteMod.module", then copy the above code inthe that file between a `<?php ?>` tag, replacing all instances of "mymodule" with "MySiteMod" then create one more file called "MySiteMod.info", and as I said just look at another modules info file to see how those are written, you just need the first few lines that define the name and version number etc.

Answer (score 2):

I like Trey's answer, but you can do it even more simply.

```
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items['homepage']=array(
    'title' => 'Home',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_homepage',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
}
function mymodule_homepage(){
  drupal_set_title(t('Some welcoming title'));
  return array();
}
```

This gives you a blank page for all users. Then create a block shown only to anonymous users and only on the front page (""). Create other blocks for other roles as needed. In this way, you don't need any special command to edit it.

Thanks Trey for confirming that there is no core way to do this. (You can use node access or front page modules, but I didn't try them because this is so lightweight.)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this module](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) can provide what you need. With it you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.